# MySql Trigger Update select sum after insert

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, sum

I have three tables.

1. Members
2. Accounts
3. Transactions

I want to update Accounts.AccountBalance with the sum of all Transactions.TransactionAmount after a new transaction is inserted into the Transactions table.

The following code does not seem to work for me.  Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewTrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON Transactions
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Accounts SET Accounts.AccountBalance = (
                SELECT SUM(Transactions.TransactionAmount) 
                    FROM Transactions
                    WHERE Accounts.AccountID=Transactions.AccountID
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewTrigger 
AFTER INSERT ON Transactions
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Accounts a
   SET a.AccountBalance = 
    (SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) 
       FROM Transactions
      WHERE AccountID = a.AccountID)
 WHERE a.AccountID = NEW.AccountID;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4e967/1)** demo.

**UPDATE**: Since triggers are not available to you try wrap `INSERT` and `UPDATE` into a stored procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE AddTransaction(IN aid INT, amount DECIMAL(11, 2)) 
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO Transactions (AccountID, TransactionAmount)
  VALUES (aid, amount);
  UPDATE Accounts a
     SET a.AccountBalance = 
      (SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) 
         FROM Transactions
        WHERE AccountID = a.AccountID)
   WHERE a.AccountID = aid;
   COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```
CALL AddTransaction(1, 10.50);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdf53/1)** demo for that scenario.

Comment: No luck.
Error
SQL query: 

CREATE TRIGGER NewTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Transactions
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE Accounts a SET a.AccountBalance = (

SELECT SUM( TransactionAmount ) 
FROM Transactions
WHERE AccountID = a.AccountID
)
WHERE a.AccountID = NEW.AccountID
MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: @MarcusReed There is no need for `BEGIN`. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: MySQL said: 

#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Comment: @MarcusReed In MySQL 5.0 [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) requires the SUPER privilege. Therefore either grant needed privileges for your current user under which you're creating a trigger, or do it under superuser (usually root) account

Comment: I am using godaddy phpmyadmin and I cant change the privileges.  Is there any other way of updating that field with the sum data?

Comment: @MarcusReed GoDaddy and other providers restrict creating triggers to shared hosting users. See http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2400/do-you-restrict-any-features-in-mysql-4150. You can simply execute `UPDATE` after `INSERT` on Transactions or better yet wrap it up in a stored procedure. (You should be able to create an SP in your GO Daddy account)

Comment: @MarcusReed See updated answer for a scenario with a stored procedure.