# Automatically calculate a database field from another table with a foreign key relation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables:

- Table A with column A-id and double field column total amount,
- Table B with foreign key column A-id and amount column.

I want the total amount in table A to change automatically, depending on the field.

Is this behavior possible to implement? Essentially, I'd like the field to hold a query that runs every time I add/delete/update a row in Table B. I'm using phpMyAdmin (if it's relevant).

I've tried using the following queries:

1. Take the current total amount and put them in a variable named i.
2. Make the changes in table B.
3. Update the new total amount in table A.

However, this hasn't been efficient.

Comment: Refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802833/mysql-trigger-update-select-sum-after-insert

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Calculate the values on-the-fly in a single query. You need to join the tables for that

```
select *, a.amount  + b.amount as total_amount
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.a_id = b.a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger to do such a kind of things.

Otherwise you should make changes by using coding itself whenever B table got changes, it should affect A table. Whatever it may add, edit, delete.